# Pass table names to a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pass tables names to the query shown below, but I am getting the following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

If I pass only one table name as follows, it works fine:

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_x'
```

So it seems the error because of multiple tables.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @ColumnCount nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Sql = STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL '+ ' '+'SELECT '''+TABLE_NAME+''' AS TABLE_NAME,'+''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''+' AS ColumName'+
     ',SUM(CASE WHEN '+COLUMN_NAME+' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As CountOfNulls
      ,COUNT('+COLUMN_NAME+') As Count ,COUNT(distinct '+COLUMN_NAME+') As CountDistinct 
     FROM '+TABLE_NAME  
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,10,'')


EXEC (@Sql)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried PRINT @Sql to show the statement it wants to execute?

Comment: @Peter no and i do not have that much experience in sql

Comment: Instead of EXEC (@Sql) do PRINT @Sql, in your SSMS messages tab the query will be shown

Comment: Why are you generating this query when you can just run it natively. Something like this is a rudimentary way to compare schemas, but there are much better ways. Perhaps explain what you are expecting to achieve

Comment: Tag your Sql Server *version* and explain what you are trying to do as there are better ways to construct this.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ColumnCount nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Sql = STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL '+ ' '+'SELECT '''+TABLE_NAME+''' AS TABLE_NAME,'+''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''+' AS ColumName'+
     ',SUM(CASE WHEN ['+COLUMN_NAME+'] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As CountOfNulls
      ,COUNT(['+COLUMN_NAME+']) As Count ,COUNT(distinct ['+COLUMN_NAME+']) As CountDistinct 
     FROM '+TABLE_NAME  
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS )
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,10,'')
--print @sql

EXEC (@Sql)
```

**As your table or column may have some keyword so it is not execute as expected, you need to add brackets [].**

**If you are getting complex execution error then you may need to get the less column / table to procced it**